# Regarding the great parashara exception

Tags: astrology

The great Parashara exception is that:
 "A planet debilitated in 3rd or 6th house confers good results."(sometimes Neecha Bhanga Rajayoga is also a criteria for this exception)
Marc Boney had written a book on it.

Say for example (Aries ascendant) Venus in 6th house is not considered good and the nature of the spouse/marriage quality is likely to be bad.(not always).

What if venus is debilitated in 6th house and has a neechabhanga raja yoga? What would be the nature of spouse then?

To be more precise is this exception confined just to produce a raja yoga or does it also alter basic interpretations of a birth chart?